# The application has stopped unexpectedly! Arraylist Hashmaps and TabHost

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, android-tabhost

I have a problem with my code and i don't seem to find it ! The error is...Application has stopped unexpectedly! I don't have a clue about what's going on. (i'm also a DevAndroid begginer)
My first tab works ok, but when i switch to the second one with the ArrayList Hashmap, it crashes.

Here is my BonuriActivity code:

```
public class BonuriActivity extends ListActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_bonuri);

    final String url="http://xxxzzz/throwdata.php?p=bonuri";

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(BonuriActivity.this,
            getBonuri(url), R.layout.list_bon, 
            new String[] {"Produs", "Cantitate", "UM", "IdVinzare"},
            new int[] { R.id.Produs, R.id.Cantitate, R.id.UM, R.id.IdVinzare });
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getBonuri(String KEY_121) {

       InputStream is = null;
       String result = "";  

       HashMap<String,String> entitiesHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> returnString = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        //http post
        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
        //parse json data
        try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);                    
                        //Get an output to the screen
                        entitiesHashMap.put("Produs", json_data.getString("Produs"));
                        entitiesHashMap.put("Cantitate", json_data.getString("Cantitate"));
                        entitiesHashMap.put("UM", json_data.getString("UM"));
                        entitiesHashMap.put("IdVinzare", json_data.getString("IdVinzare"));
                        returnString.add(entitiesHashMap);
                }
        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        return returnString; 
    }     

}
```

And here is my TabBonuri.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tab2Layout">

<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my list_bon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/UM"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:text="UM"
android:textSize="16sp"
>
</TextView>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/Cantitate"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="21px"
android:padding="10dp"
android:text="Cantitate"
android:textSize="16sp"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/Produs"
android:layout_width="121px"
android:layout_height="22px"
android:padding="10dp"
android:text="Produs"
android:textSize="16sp"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/IdVinzare"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="invisible"
android:text="TextView"
/>
</LinearView>
```

I gradly thank you for your time spent helping me.
Please comment if you see why is my program crashing, cause i'm already stressed out with this ('ve been on this for 2 days, it's frustrating).

Comment: Please post the error message

Comment: You are asking your code to do an internet call on the UI thread. So your acitivty is going slow and not responding. Try moving the processing (internet call) to it's own thread

Comment: @Blundell: He would get a "not responding" message instead of a "stopped unexpectedly" or am I wrong?

Comment: @Warren I would of thought he would get "Not Responding" in the app and then he hits force close and gets "stopped unexpectedly" in eclipse? I may be wrong :)  @Tache we need the error message from your LogCat!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have no idea where you can find the LogCat...

If you develop with Eclipse, take a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html
The error message you will find there is what we need to help you. So copy&paste it into your question.

If you want to learn how to debug, here is a small how to for it: http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html

**update**

Ok a screenshot from logcat isn't the best way to provide the error but it shows what Blundell suggested: You fetch from the internet in the UI thread. Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html and the fetching of your internet stuff should be done with that: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thank you all for replying. Yes, i had no ideea where i could find LogCat. So, this is what LogCat told me when the application stopped: http://i55.tinypic.com/1zl4x36.jpg ....i'm still confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just create a new Thread and use a Handler:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class BonuriActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final int PASS = 0;
private static final int FAIL = 1;

private final String url = "http://xxxzzz/throwdata.php?p=bonuri";

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bonnieList = null;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_bonuri);

    fetchData();
}

private void fetchData() {
    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait", "loading..", true);
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do the internet call in it's own thread
            bonnieList = getBonuri(url);
            // Call back to the UI thread with the result
            if (bonnieList != null || !bonnieList.isEmpty()) {
                doAfterInternetCall.sendEmptyMessage(PASS);
            } else {
                doAfterInternetCall.sendEmptyMessage(FAIL);
            }
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }.start();
}

private Handler doAfterInternetCall = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case PASS:
            actUponRetreivedData();
            break;
        case FAIL:
            // TODO do something else
            break;
        }
    }
};

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getBonuri(String KEY_121) {

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";

    HashMap<String, String> entitiesHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> returnString = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    // parse json data
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            // Get an output to the screen
            entitiesHashMap.put("Produs", json_data.getString("Produs"));
            entitiesHashMap.put("Cantitate", json_data.getString("Cantitate"));
            entitiesHashMap.put("UM", json_data.getString("UM"));
            entitiesHashMap.put("IdVinzare", json_data.getString("IdVinzare"));
            returnString.add(entitiesHashMap);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return returnString;
}

protected void actUponRetreivedData() {
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(BonuriActivity.this, bonnieList, R.layout.list_bon, new String[] { "Produs", "Cantitate", "UM", "IdVinzare" }, new int[] { R.id.Produs,
            R.id.Cantitate, R.id.UM, R.id.IdVinzare });
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

This may not be guaranteed to work I'll check it later, but it show's the principle of threads and handlers.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Blundell. I will figure it out now, 'cause i have time.